# SAS EG : Selecting the most recent dataset from a library

Tags: sas

I use [sas](/questions/tagged/sas) EG V5.1. I need to select the most recent dataset saved within a permanent library. How can I do that without having to look at the library?

```
employee_2016_09_04
employee_2016_09_15
first_2016_09_04
first_2016_09_14
```

I need to select the most recent tables of either category and these are SAS datasets. I currently have a macro variable defined for the date which I update manually each time I run a code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dictionary tables`.

Using modification (`modate`) or creation column (`crdate`).

```
proc sql;
    create table tables as
    select memname, modate 
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = 'SASHELP'
    order by modate desc;
quit;
```

Or use sort on variable name (`memname`).

```
proc sql;
    create table tables as
    select memname 
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = 'SASHELP'
    order by memname desc;
quit;
```

Or the same thing using `sashelp` views

```
data tables;
    set sashelp.vtable;
    where libname = 'SASHELP';
    keep memname modate;
run;

proc sort data=tables;
    by descending modate;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I can figure out the most recent datasets. Is there a way I could read the observations without having to look at this table?